# Counting number of pages in tif image file using java

Tags: java, file, tiff

How can i count the number of pages in tiff file? i get it as byte array

Thanks

Comment: This question is extremely unclear yet specific on a certain issue - somehow i think its a homework?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of pages using the Java Advanced Imaging API. I.e. Using:

[ImageDecoder.getNumPages()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/index.html)

An example of how to use it can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120419010410/http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/samples/MultiPageRead.java).

Comment: I get the file in byte array, How can i count the number of pages quickly if i not need to create it, only to save it in byte array

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at iText. iText provides you a class called [TiffImage](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/TiffImage.html).

```
TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(/* your file, input stream or byte array */));
```

Comment: **Warning** : This API loads the whole tiff file into memory as byte[], hence will impact scale and performance negatively in high load conditions.