# Unable to get number of page for .tif file

Tags: java, tiff

I have tiff files and I want to get the number of pages. I have been followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436445/counting-number-of-pages-in-tif-image-file-using-java) question, however I am unable to get the number of pages. There are no errors and I have tried to debug the problem but cannot find the cause.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import javax.media.jai.widget.ScrollingImagePanel;
import javax.media.jai.NullOpImage;
import javax.media.jai.OpImage;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDecodeParam;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;




public class FileSearch {

    int sizeOfFile = Integer.parseInt((JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Size: ")));

    public void findFiles(File root) throws IOException {

        File[] listOfFiles = root.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            String iName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && iName.endsWith(".tif")) {

                long fileSize = listOfFiles[i].length();

                if (fileSize <= (sizeOfFile*1000)) {
                    File file = new File("\\\\server\\folder1\\TestFiles\\" + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        System.out.println(file.getName() + " already exists");
                    } else {
                        File folder = new File("\\\\server\\folder1\\TestFiles\\\\Files by Size\\Files of size " + ((sizeOfFile*1000) / 1000) + " KB");
                        if (!folder.exists()) {
                            if (folder.mkdir()) {
                                System.out.println("Folder : " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }

                        /* Start here */

                        SeekableStream s = new FileSeekableStream(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\file.tif")); //using this file as test

                        TIFFDecodeParam param = null;

                        ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(".tif", s, param);

                        System.out.println("Number of images in this TIFF: " +
                                           dec.getNumPages());
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dec.getNumPages());
/* END HERE */

                        try{
                            System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName() + " | " + FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(fileSize));
                            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(listOfFiles[i], folder);                          
                        }
                        catch(IOException e){
                            System.out.println("Same files");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(listOfFiles[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed `ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", s, param);` to `ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder(".tif", s, param);` to see for any different results.

Comment: What happen? Nothing? It works on local date?

Comment: @Zaknafein, as I said in my post, there are no errors.

Comment: Your code is the same as mine (mine works with "tiff" and not ".tif").  You said there were no error messages but didn't say what output you did get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question :

Change the below between START TO END section

```
RenderedImage renderedImage[], page;
File tiffFile = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\file.tif");

SeekableStream seekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(tiffFile);
ImageDecoder imageDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff",seekableStream, null);
renderedImage = new RenderedImage[imageDecoder.getNumPages()];

int tifPageCount = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < imageDecoder.getNumPages(); k++) {
    renderedImage[k] = imageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(k);
    tifPageCount++;
}
```